# Determine which li tag was clicked

Tags: jquery

I have this script:

```js
(function() {
   'use strict';

   $("#mynav").click(function() {        

   }) 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="mynav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m1">m1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m2">m2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m3">m3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m4">m4</a>
      </li>          
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

How I can use panel to determine which li was clicked using "panel" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.target` to clicked element and `attr('panel')` to get panel value.

```js
$("#mynav").click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr('panel'))  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="mynav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m1">m1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m2">m2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m3">m3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" panel="m4">m4</a></li>          
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access $(this) within that scope :)

Comment: I need to check panel value

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('panel')`. Please note that `panel` is not a valid attribute for element `a`. If you want to provide custom attributes for an element, [use data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). You can access data attributes via `$(this).attr('data-panel')` or `$(this).data('panel')`.